# Child window freeze if opened during parent window resize

Tags: c++, winapi

I have some window. User can drag it, resize etc. At some point there can be a message that should be shown in modal window. I'm creating such a window as child and setting parent window to disabled. Everything works ok except the case when I'm dragging a parent window during the child creation. I used spy to see messages and found that in that case my child window doesn't receives `WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE` message. It seems that parent's `WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE` blocks one for child. I tried to manually send `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE` for the parent but unfortunatelly this doesn't works.

Answer (score 1):

Send the [`WM_CANCELMODE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632615(v=vs.85).aspx) message to your parent window before displaying the dialog box.

> Sent to cancel certain modes, such as mouse capture. For example, the
>   system sends this message to the active window when a dialog box or
>   message box is displayed. Certain functions also send this message
>   explicitly to the specified window regardless of whether it is the
>   active window. For example, the EnableWindow function sends this
>   message when disabling the specified window

Comment: Congratulations for hitting the 20k.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Unfortunately this didn't help. Even more, when I'm showing a child window, I'm disabling a parent and this action sends `WM_CANCELMODE` internally.